# PowerShell based Process specific resource monitoring

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage

I am using PowerShell for some benchmarking of Autodesk Revit, and I would like to add some resource monitoring. I know I can get historical CPU utilization and RAM utilization in general, but I would like to be able to poll Process specific CPU and RAM utilization every 5 seconds or so.
In addition, I would love to be able to poll how many cores a process is currently using, the clock speed of those specific cores, and the frame rate of the screen that process is currently displayed on.
Are those things even accessible via PowerShell/.NET? Or is that low level stuff I just can't get to with PS?

Comment: why not just use perfmon.exe?

Comment: The key is I am using PowerShell to drive Revit using some TXT based "journal" files that provide the meat of the benchmark. I want to be able to monitor resource use during different phases of the benchmark, so I can report things like # of cores in use, speed of those cores, % of those cores in use, etc. But, if I understand what Perfmon does, it is global. I need to specifically show when Revit is using one core vs 8, etc.

Comment: And I have a graphics test I want to run too, and showing FPS would be useful there, but only for the screen Revit is on. Lots of Revit users have 2-3 27" screens, so a generic number isn't useful, I need to be sure I am reporting performance on the Revit hosting screen, while Revit is doing something where frame rate is pertinent.